# Angularjs ng-repeat join records

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am looking to find the best approach (Angular way) to accomplish the following:
I have an array with a list of messages, each message contains the name of the author, the text and the timestamp of when it was written.
Each message is drawn in a table, however messages can be stacked together given that:

- The author of the current message is the same as the previous one
- The height of the previous table row does not surpass a given limit height (i.e 40% of the total available height).

The layout looks something like this:

```
message = { author: 'x', message: 'Hello World', timeStamp: new Date() }

table
tbody
    tr( data-ng-repeat = 'message in conversation.messages | parseMessage')
        td.self
            div.messageAuthorProfile( style = 'background-image: url(/pictures/{{ message.author | parseAuthorEmail }}/profile/0.jpg)')
                div.conversation
                    label.messageAuthorName {{ message.author | parseAuthorName }}
                    div.message
                        div.conversationTimeStamp
                            span {{ message.timeStamp | parseTimeStamp }}
                        div.conversationMessage
                            p {{ message.message }}
```

This can 'easily' be achieved using jquery by getting the last element of the table, checking its height and appending the message if the conditions are met, however I am struggling to achieve this functionality in a pure Angular.js solution.

Could any one give me some insight on possible ways to achieve this?

Best Regards and Thanks for reading!

Disclaimer: I only got started with angular.js for about a week so I am currently learning by porting a couple of projects 100% jquery based to angular, however after researching and checking the online documentation I couldn't come up with a 'clean way' of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think of this is to think of how you would do this with your array data and then have your view reflect the data.

So if I am understanding your question, you are trying to group the rows by the authors.
I tend to use underscore.js for array manipulation ( it is very good for it)
http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy

It will group your data by the author.
Then in your angular view, have 2 ng-repeats.  the outer ng-repeat for your groups, and the inner for the message and timestamp.
This will show the messages and timestamps listed for each author.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anton! Unfortunately I think I did not make myself clear, messages can either be loaded from cache or sent in real time and they are sorted by timeStamp (sent timing), therefore they are only stacked per user if they are consecutive, being the second requirement that the modelling of the data ( in this case the table row) isn't bigger than lets say 200 px.

Comment: Especially with complex cached or realtime grouping business logic,  group your data by the rules you need, this becomes crucial if you have realtime data being added to the model. Then use the view logic in my answer.  With the 200px, that is view logic which would be super simple by setting the css max-height to 200px